# Request for books/articles on random polynomials

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, polynomials

Can somebody kindly recommend me a couple of introductory books/articles on random polynomials with clear expositions of fundamental results (like the distribution of roots, expected number of real zeroes etc) and some indications of connections and probable applications? Thanking you in advance for any help.

Comment: I posted this question on mathestackexchage as well but received no responce. Here is the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3821219/request-for-recommendations-for-random-polynomials

Comment: Half a day is far too soon. People live in all the timezones, you know. Maybe the person who could answer your question hasn't been on the internet since you posted it...

Comment: @ David Roberts ,my apologies ,i will bear this thing in mind next time i cross post

Answer (score 3):

The two old but interesting books for random polynomials are

1. A. T. Bharucha-Reid, M. Sambandham. *Random polynomials*. Probability and Mathematical Statistics, Academic Press, Inc., Orlando, Fla., 1986.
2. K. Farahmand. *Topics in random polynomials*. Pitman research notes in mathematics series 393, Longman, Harlow, 1998.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend the article by Edelman and Kostlan: https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1995-32-01/S0273-0979-1995-00571-9/